# Specifying Silverlight combobox popup direction (dropup)

Tags: silverlight, combobox, direction

Is it possible to make the silverlight combo-box "drop up" i.e. display the popup above the combo-box instead of bellow as per default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to define your own ComboBox Template, that contains the definition of the Popup. Edit a copy using Blend for example.

However, placing that Popup above is not an easy task as Silverlight Popups have no `Placement`or `PlacementTarget` properties like in WPF that would allow to display it above.

Luckily [Kent Boogaart wrote an Attached Behavior](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2010/07/silverlight-popup-with-target-placement.html) that adds this capability and it is used like this:

```
<Popup b:PopupPlacement.PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ContentPresenterBorder}">
    <b:Popup.PreferredOrientations>
        <b:PopupOrientationCollection>
            <b:PopupOrientation Placement="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <b:PopupOrientation Placement="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <b:PopupOrientation Placement="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <b:PopupOrientation Placement="Right" VerticalAlignment="TopCenter"/>
        </b:PopupOrientationCollection>
    </b:Popup.PreferredOrientations>

    <!--Popup content with the ItemPresenter-->
</Popup>
```

Where `ContentPresenterBorder` is the name of the container that holds the ToggleButton of the ComboBox.

Comment: Would it be possible post the code at a different location? The https://skydrive.live.com address in the above link is blocked by my company's proxy server... (or perhaps just paste the source into a separate answer? That may be better in case the file is ever deleted/moved/etc)

Comment: If your company is blocking Microsoft sites while you're working on their technologies, you're in trouble :) There are too much files to paste them here, what would be a suitable location for you? Or by e-mail?

Comment: Thanks Mart, I agree blocking sites is usually not very productive. I ended up emailing myself the files from home, so I'm all set.